# Launched failed. Binary not found c++ eclipse

Tags: c++, mingw, eclipse-kepler

I have no idea why my c++ file  will not compile correctly. I added the MinGW installer in the right environment path. I selected my Binary parser to PE Windows Parser. [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt from any folder and type `make`. Press enter. If it gives you a message like `file not found`, then you either do not have `make` on the path, or it was not installed with Mingw.

So if not found, first go to the Mingw folder and verify that you have a file called `make.exe`. If you don't, you need to reinstall (possibly with msys), if you do, then you need to make sure that the exact folder with `make` is on your path.

You can see what folders are on your path by running `echo %PATH%` in a command prompt.

Comment: Where would the make.exe file be at in the mingw folder. And if I have that file, then what would i do?

Comment: I just looked at my installation, which is quite old. I saw the make exe in my msys installation (C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin). In any event, you need to specifically the 'make' path (in my case C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin) to your system path.

Comment: Okay I located that path(C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin). Where do I need to add that path to and how would I add it?

Comment: Just replace Cygwin with Mingw, and put in the appropriate path.